# Update child attributes rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a customer model and book_room model

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :book_rooms
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :book_rooms
end

class BookRoom < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

in the book_room controller the create method is from its parent

```
class BookRoomsController < ApplicationController
 def create 
   @customer = Customer.find(params[:customer_id]) 
   @customer_room = @customer.book_rooms.create(book_rooms_params)
   flash[:notice] = "Customer has been added to room"
   redirect_to customer_path(@customer)
 end 
 def destroy 
   @customer = Customer.find(params[:customer_id]) 
   @customer_room = @customer.book_rooms.find(params[:id])
   @customer_room.destroy
   flash[:notice] = "Customer room has been deleted"
   redirect_to customer_path(@customer)
 end 
 def edit 
   @customer = Customer.find(params[:customer_id]) 
 end  
 def update 
   @customer = Customer.find(params[:customer_id]) 
   @customer.book_rooms.update(book_rooms_params)
   flash[:notice] = "Customer has checked out"
   redirect_to @customer
 end 
 private
 def book_rooms_params 
   params.require(:book_room).permit(:room, :first_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :checked_out)
 end
```

end

in the Customer show page

```
<%= form_for [@customer, @customer.book_rooms.build] do |f| %>
<% @room = Room.all %>
<%= f.label "Room: "%>
<%= f.select(:room, @room.collect { |a| [a.room_number, a.id] }) %>
<%= f.submit "Enter" %>
<div class="col-md-12"><%= render @customer.book_rooms.order("created_at DESC") %></div>
```

This works perfectly and all child objects get created. now when I try to edit the child attributes it doesn't update at all

heres the edit form in the book_room edit page/action

```
<%= form_for @customer do |f| %>
<%= f.fields_for :book_rooms, @customer.book_rooms do |f| %>
  <%= f.check_box :checked_out %>
<% end %>
<%= f.submit "Enter" %>
```

is there something i am doing wrong? why doesn't it update?

Customers controller

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_customer, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
# POST /customers.json
def create
@customer = Customer.new(customer_params)
respond_to do |format|
  if @customer.save
    format.html { redirect_to @customer, notice: 'Customer was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @customer }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @customer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @customer.update(customer_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @customer, notice: 'Customer was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @customer }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @customer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
  end
end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_customer
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def customer_params
  params.require(:customer).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :sex, :book_rooms_attributes => [:checked_out])
end
```

Comment: You are only showing your `create` action.. where is your `update` action and what is in your `book_rooms_params` method?

Comment: Have you a customers_controller ? normally, `<%= form_for @customer do |f| %>` via customer/[customer_id] (update).

Comment: Ok, you need to add `:id` inside the `:book_rooms_attributes => [:checked_out]`. After that you will be able to update. otherwise every time you will be ended up with new records.

Comment: yh adding the id works! and also im having problems where it generates a checkbox for all the child objects in the edit action instead of for just the one selected.. why is that?

Answer (score 1):

In your customers controller :
Try to change your function customer_params like:

```
def customer_params
  params.require(:customer).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :sex,  {:book_rooms => [:checked_out]})
end
```

For more explications see [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit)

Answer (score 1):

Change your `update` method to:

```
def update 
   @customer = Customer.find(params[:customer_id]) 
   if @customer.update_attributes(customer_params)
     flash[:notice] = "Customer has checked out"
     redirect_to @customer
   else
    ...redirect to edit page with a flash error message ...
   end

end
```

You also need to modify your edit page.

`<%= form_for(:customer, :url => {:action => 'update', :id => @customer.id}, :method => 'PUT') do |f| %>`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the URL to update and changing the method to `patch` you will go to update method.

```
<%= form_for :customer, url: customer_path(@customer),method: :patch  do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :book_rooms, @customer.book_rooms do |f| %>
      <%= f.check_box :checked_out %>
    <% end %>
<%= f.submit "Enter" %>
```